# is there a way to paste HTML code from Dreamweaver on MS Word with the Dreamweaver code colors

Tags: html, colors, ms-word, dreamweaver

is there a way to paste HTML code  from Dreamweaver on MS Word with the same colors that Dreamweaver adds to all diferents commands?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the HEX ID of colors or something?

EDIT: You can try a text editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text that has syntax highlighting (and customization).

Comment: I think he's trying to maintain the syntax highlighting from Dreamweaver when he pastes code into MS Word.

Comment: Oh, then why not just use Notepad++ or Sublime to edit the code with the option to customize syntax highlighting colors?

Comment: I'm not sure what his particular use case is but it seems like he might be trying to "embed" the code for a paper or report in MS Word or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) instead of MS Word. It also shows all the colours of the different markup tags.